# In CMake how to create targets with identical names?

Tags: cmake

I have a question regarding **CMake** and I need help to solve the following error I'm getting:

```
CMake Error at :::: (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "generate" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory :::::.
```

Here the target names of the two same level `CMakeLists.txt` are the same and I want to keep them identical, without any conflict. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I think that is not possible. As far as I know target names must be unique. Otherwise a command like ````cmake --build . --target generate```` could not know which of the two custom targets you want to build. If the generate target belongs to a binary target you could name it something like generate_binaryTarget.

Comment: You could also use the keyword `APPEND` with `add_custom_command()` if you want to group something under the same `make` target. Could you please give a [mcve] of your CMake code so we could suggest a solution?

Comment: add_custom_target(
cleanall ${} 
COMMAND ${}
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${}
)
This is what I am doing - This command cleanall exists in two CmakeLists and it had a conflict at the time of Make. As it is not able to understand which one to invoke

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According with CMake policy [`CMP0002`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/policy/CMP0002.html) (introduced by CMake 2.6, emphasis mine):

> **Targets names created with** add_executable, add_library, or **add_custom_target** are logical build target names. Logical target names **must be globally unique** [...]

The following note deserves a mention and could probably help you anyway:

> Custom targets must simply have globally unique names (unless one uses the global property `ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS` with a Makefiles generator).

It means that there exists a global property named [`ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_gbl/ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS.html) that is probably what you are looking for. It has a limited use and you should read carefully the documentation, but it's worth a try.
The most relevant part follows:

> Makefile generators are capable of supporting duplicate custom target names. [...] However, setting this property will cause non-Makefile generators to produce an error and refuse to generate the project.

To be able to use duplicate custom targets put the following line in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS TRUE)
```

If it solves your issue mainly depends on the actual problem, so I cannot say.

Comment: Thanks @skypjack. I will give it a try.. Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: This is not working with Version 2.6. Do I need to add anything else??

Comment: _introduced by CMake 2.6_ - probably you did something wrong somewhere else in your `CMakeLists.tx`, but it should work since version 2.6.

Comment: It's working, I had a mistake in the syntax of it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Nikitha You're welcome. I'm glad it works as expected. Do not forget to accept an answer if it solves the problem. It will help future readers.

Comment: What this answer and also the official documentation lacks, is an explanation what actually happens when `ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS` is set, multiple targets with the same name are generated, and one executes that target with make.

Answer (score 6):

This could be a good help:

> OUTPUT_NAME sets the real name of a target when it is built and can be used to help create two targets of the same name even though CMake requires unique logical target names.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html

Comment: How does this help? CMake requires target names to be unique _before_ generating the build files. We could have targets named `foo1` and `foo2` that both generate a target `foo` in the output Makefiles (or other build system), but not vice versa.

Comment: Because, @Thomas, it's possible that that the original poster wanted the output to be identical (e.g. library + executable), but did not know it was possible to differentiate between the target label in CMake and the name of the output file.